# Automatically analyse my work - time control on browser and other apps

Tags: windows, software-rec, browser-addons

I need some software that can analyze my daily time usage for application and browsing websites to be more productive and to see where I lose time. -

For example:

**Monday:**

- Office Word 2 hours
- Google Chrome - 3 hours
- Outlook - 1 hour
- Photoshop - 30 minutes ...
- Media player 2 hours ....

And another software for analysing time spent on all internet sites - BROWSER

- Google - 2 hours
- Facebook - 1 hour
- Gmail - 3 hours
- YouTube.com 1.5 hours
- Super User - 3 hours and so on

It must work automatically, I am not yet so much disciplined that I will note time when start and finish.

And track my sessions on internet for minimum one week or always working in the back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **[Manic Time](http://www.manictime.com/)**.  Free and pro versions, the free version will do the job well.

[image]

This program can be configured to start on boot and keeps track of all programs running on your PC.  It also logs every web page you visit, regardless of browser.  For the kind of information you're looking for, just visit the `Statistics` tab and it will tell you:

- How long you've spent on various webpages (e.g. 4.6 hours on Facebook)
- How many hours you've used your computer in the last day/week/month/year
- Lots of other various details.

<sub>I am not affiliated with the product in any way, shape, or form.</sub>